# Raspberry Pi stream USB through to ethernet?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi2

I am looking into ways to stream a usb camera over long distances. The plan is to plug the USB into a raspberry pi2, then send it over wifi via TCP. Is this a viable plan?

I have found a few approaches like this:

https://www.virtualhere.com/

But They seem to be for printers and other 'static' devices. Will a streaming data connection work with this type of approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a USB camera uses the "isochronous" transfer mode of the USB protocol.

VirtualHere and most other usb/ip software support this mode.

The main issue is network latency. The lower the webcam resolution, the less latency will be a problem. Also, the pi2 has a fast CPU however the USB bus is shared with the Ethernet so by definition throughput is cut in half, perhaps looking at a embedded board that doesn't share the USB bus like a beaglebone or odroid-c1 or other board would provide better performance for the same price.

(I am the author of VirtualHere)

Comment: Thanks Micheal, Appreciated. I will look into those other board options.